# mysql select * from <tablename>

Tags: mysql

i have a table in a mysql database.

in that table is a field with a tablename as value.

For example:

```
Row Tablename
1   table_x
2   table_y
3   table_z
```

tables x, y and z are real tables except they are table_x_log, table_y_log and table_z_log.

Al *_log tables have a column called 'mutation'. The possible values for this record is 'insert' of 'update'.

How can I query all tables to have the following resulttable (or something like that)

```
tablename    mutation count
table_x_log  insert   12
table_x_log  update   22
table_y_log  insert   32
table_y_log  update   18
table_z_log  insert   3
table_z_log  update   74
```

To improve my question:
I'm planning to create a recovery script because the database has a manual written type of synchronization. Doing this application site is possible, but creates to much overhead. It's not something I'm planning to repeat, I have to run this type of query just once.

Comment: This is going to require some dynamic SQL. What kind of application code are you planning to do this with? It may be easier to just do it application-side than to stuff it all into a stored procedure in the RDBMS.

Comment: i improved my question, thank you for thinking with me

Comment: How many different table names?  Is it few enough the names could be coded into the query?  (if not, why is it bad to write a small mysql app or script that pulls data and creates the query?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MYSQL TRIGGER`

Syntax:

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
TRIGGER trigger_name
trigger_time trigger_event
ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Comment: What is your idea on using a trigger for this problem? he is probably using the triggers to fill the log_ tables, but not likely to use them to do this query.

Comment: I do not see the use of triggers in this case, thank you for thinking with me.